# XCTKVOExpectation usage example in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I want to write unit tests in objective c. For that I need to run my tests only when the key value of an observed object becomes an expected valued.

The apple documentation does not explain the implementation in detail. Any example code will be of great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example implementation in Swift, I hope this shows you how KVO expectations can be used.

The handler that is passed to the expectation takes two objects as input (the object you are observing and a dictionary of changes). It should return `true` if you are satisfied that the value has changed as you expected, and `false` if the expectation has not been met.

```
class Person: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func changeName(to newName: String) {
        name = newName
    }
}

class Tests: XCTestCase {
    func testNameValueChangedWhenChangeNameCalled() {
        let person = Person(name: "Alice")
        let newName = "Bob"
        keyValueObservingExpectation(for: person, keyPath: "name", handler: { (observedObject, change) in
            // `observedObject` is of type `Any` so it needs to be cast as the correct type before proceeding
            guard let observedObject = observedObject as? Person else {
                // Don't fulfill the expectation
                return false
            }
            // Check the current name is the name we expect
            return observedObject.name == newName
        })
        person.changeName(to: newName)
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1, handler: nil)
    }
}
```

You can also initialize an `XCTKVOExpectation` directly and use `XCTWaiter` to handle outcomes with more granularity.

```
let person = Person(name: "Alice")
let newName = "Bob"
let expectation = XCTKVOExpectation(keyPath: "name", object: person)
expectation.handler = { (observedObject, change) in
    guard let observedObject = observedObject as? Person else {
        return false
    }
    return observedObject.name == newName
}
person.changeName(to: newName)
let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
XCTAssertEqual(result, .completed)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the normal expectation and needed this, but there was not much documentation on this. Worked just how I needed. You can also return true or false to tell the expectation handler to fulfill the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use keyValueObservingExpectation:

```
let testClass = MyViewController()
let expectation = keyValueObservingExpectation(for: testClass, keyPath: #keyPath(MyViewController.urlString))
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
```

To use that you have to specify keyPath using #keyPath(MyViewController.urlString). In that code it is under observation the value for urlString.

Here is another example of this https://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/kvo-quick-spec-unit-tests/